# Create an odoo order and invoice it via external API

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-16, ripcord

I'm trying to integrate an third party application with odoo, the application should create the order and confirm it, to generate the invoice, the order creation works perfectly, when executing the `create_invoices` nothing shows and no errors appears.

```
require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

$url = "http://127.0.0.1:8069";
$db = "odoo";
$password = "";
$username = "";

$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());
$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");



$order_data = array(
    'partner_id' => 12, // Customer ID 
    'date_order' => date('Y-m-d'), // Order Date 
    // 'pricelist_id' => 1, // Price List ID 
    'state' => 'draft', // Order Status (draft) 

    'order_line' => array(array(0, 0, array( // Order Line Items 

        'product_id' => 2, // Product ID 
        'name' => 'Product Name', // Product Name  
        'product_uom_qty' => 5.00, // Quantity of Product  
        'price_unit' => 10.00, // Unit Price of Product  

    )))
);

$order_id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'sale.order', 'create', array($order_data));

// Confirm Order and Create Invoice

if ($order_id) {

    $confirmOrder = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'sale.order', 'action_confirm', array($order_id));

    if ($confirmOrder) {

        $invoiceCreate = $models->execute_kw(
            $db,
            $uid,
            $password,
            'sale.advance.payment.inv',
            'create_invoices',
            array(
                'sale_order_ids' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                    array(
                        0 => 6,
                        1 => false,
                        2 =>
                        array(
                            0 => $order_id,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'advance_payment_method' => 'delivered',
                'deduct_down_payments' => true,
                'product_id' => false,
                'fixed_amount' => 0,
                'amount' => 0,
                'deposit_account_id' => false,
                'deposit_taxes_id' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                    array(
                        0 => 6,
                        1 => false,
                        2 => array(),
                    ),
                ),
            )
            
            ,
            array(
                "context" => array(
                    'active_model' => "sale.order",
                    "allowed_company_ids" => array(1),
                    'active_id' => $order_id, "active_ids" => array($order_id)
                )
            )
        );

        if ($invoiceCreate) {
            
            echo "Order and Invoice #$invoiceCreate for Order #$order_id created successfully!\n";
        } else {
            echo "Error creating invoice!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error confirming order!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error creating order!";
}
```

Comment: Code looks good so far, i didn't get into full detail. Did you check your product settings? You're using method `delivered` for invoice creation. Is everything delivered automatically? Without that, the wizard `sale.advance.payment.inv` won't create invoices.

Comment: I tried to inspect the browser request and it looks the same, it works in browser, but nothing happens when execute the api command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `create_invoices`, Odoo will consider the first parameter as [ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/api.py#L444), to see the function call details change the `log_level` to `debug`

You should see the following debug message:

```
DEBUG demo16 odoo.api: call sale.advance.payment.inv('s', 'a', 'l', 'e', '_', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'e', 'r', '_', 'i', 'd', 's').create_invoices('advance_payment_method', 'deduct_down_payments', 'product_id', 'fixed_amount', 'amount', 'deposit_account_id', 'deposit_taxes_id')
```

Odoo will fail to call `create_invoices` function.

To fix the issue you can call the  `create` function to get a wizard record id then call the `create_invoices`

***Example:***

```
$wizard_ids = $models->execute_kw(
    $db,
    $uid,
    $password,
    'sale.advance.payment.inv',
    'create',
    array(array(
        'sale_order_ids' => array($order_id),
    )),
    array(
        "context" => array(
            'active_model' => "sale.order",
            "allowed_company_ids" => array(1),
            'active_id' => $order_id, "active_ids" => array($order_id)
        )
    )
);
    
$invoiceCreate = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'sale.advance.payment.inv', 'create_invoices', array($wizard_ids));
```